# Why can't I find lsvirtualenv command?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I want to find how many virtual environments on my machine, and I ran:

```
lsvirtualenv
```

But received the error message:

```
-bash: lsvirtualenv: command not found
```

I didn't use anaconda to create my virtual environments.

Comment: `virtualenv` has no such feature out of the box. It just creates a folder where pip can install project-local packages. Extra tools like `conda` and `pyenv` can give you broader system-wide environment visibility. That said, if you follow a convention in what you name your virtualenv directories, you can use find: `find ~ -type d -name .venv`

Comment: @wbadart I did some searches and found others saying that the command 'lsvirtualenv' can do the job on stackoverflow.  I am working on Mac.

Answer (score 11):

`lsvirtualenv` is a part of [virtualenvwrapper](/questions/tagged/virtualenvwrapper).

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

and follow [installation instructions](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

Comment: command not found even after installing virutalenvwrapper

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder Did you follow all the instructions including `source virtualenvwrapper.sh` ?

Comment: No, I had not. After doing the proper steps it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `virtualenvwrapper`

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Then after installation you have to create/edit `.bash_profile` file with following

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have `virtualenvwrapper` installed, as others have also indicated. However, I would recommend using the command below for installation:

```
python3 -m pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Here, I have explicitly specified the exact version of Python that I want to use. Then run the command `find ~/.local -name virtualenvwrapper.sh` to locate the script. Then `source /home/<userName>/.local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh`.