# Is there a way to list all python virtual environments created using the venv module?

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda, python-venv

Conda allows me to list all virtual environments [as shown here.](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#viewing-a-list-of-your-environments) The commands are:

```
conda info --envs OR conda env list
```

---

I want to do that using pip. Does pip have any option to list all virtual environments created by me ? I have created a virtual environment on my desktop but I cannot figure out a way to list it along with the base environment.

Comment: A workaround might be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55111188/4335378).

Comment: @andreis11 Only if one uses `virtualenvwrapper` for all environments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I list all the virtual environments created with venv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60873454/how-can-i-list-all-the-virtual-environments-created-with-venv)

Comment: "I want to do that using pip. Does pip have any option to list all virtual environments created by me ?" _pip_ doesn't have much to do with virtual environments. Are you are talking about [`venv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), or maybe [`virtualenv`](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, not in an easy way.

Python virtual environments created with venv, virtualenv and most other python-only virtual environments can be stored **anywhere** on the disk.  And AFAIK they are not indexed, they are truly isolated (after all you can just remove venv directory and be done with it, you don't need to do anything special). They are also unmanaged by an environment manager.  So that would require entire disk scan. Which potentially can be done (you can search for all Python executables for example) but is rather painful.

It works with miniconda because miniconda manages other packages and files that it installs, so it places venvs in concrete path, e.g. `/home/username/miniconda/envs/`.

Answer (score 1):

One indirect way is to run below command and see the directories where the python executable resides. Some of the paths will be python virtual environments and you can verify it by listing the files in those paths.

```
$ whereis python
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `pip`, though; it's just a matter of disk indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conda to create and manage venv and virtualenv environments and other packages installed using pip.

First create a conda environment with CONDA AND PIP installed into it, e.g.,

```
conda create --name core --channel conda-forge python=3.9 conda pip
```

Here I created the conda environment named "core" and installed Python 3.9, conda, and pip into it.  So now the 'core' conda environment functions like an administrative environment shell.  By installing conda into the conda environment, conda will track packages installed by pip into that environment.  You must use "pip install" INSIDE this new conda environment, so conda will index and track those pip package installations.  However, conda will still not index and centrally manage the venv environments, like it does for its own conda environments.

Here is a very good detailed guide that explains how and why to use conda and pip for virtual environments.  It covers the important aspect of using conda and pip together.

[Why You Need Python Environments and How to Manage Them with Conda](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/why-you-need-python-environments-and-how-to-manage-them-with-conda-85f155f4353c/)

[Create virtual environments for python with conda](https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/)

Comment: The question was specifically about 'venv' Python module. Conda is not always suitable for production environment, particularly when .yml file mixes conda and pip installations. With Python's 'venv' it is also possible to list just the top installed packages without all the dependencies (with pip-chill, not pip-freeze). There is no easy way (so far) to extract the top packages from conda's .yml file, and there is a fair chance that one of the dependencies will break when installing the environment from .yml.

Answer (score 0):

To list all the venv directories in the current directory
and its subdirectories, you can try this :

```
find . -type d -name "*.venv"
```